# Corner radius in button is not changing, what to do?

Tags: android, button, styles, cornerradius

I'm trying to make simple button style with 100dp corner radius (working in Intellije Idea).

That's the code:

```
<corners android:radius="100dp"/>

<solid android:color="@color/green"/>

<padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        />

<size
        android:width="110dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        />
```

I can't find problem... Because the target button i'm trying to change is not actually changing. It seems that the corner radius is not changing!
[that's my button with 100dp!!! corner radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R7EB.jpg)

Comment: What if you turn the radius down to 1dp or 2dp? Does it get smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"/>

<solid android:color="@color/green"/>

<padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        />

<size
        android:width="110dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        />

</shape>
```